# Angular-ui typeahead giving correct results only on backspace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using Angular-UI typeahead which works fine, but I am having a strange behaviour that when I press backspace, then it gives the correct results.

---

Let's say that I am typing

> sector 4

Then it gives the result as

> Sector 1 
>   Sector 2 
>   **Sector 4** 
>   Sector 5

But when I press backspace, it gives the **correct** result as

> **Sector 4** 
>   **Sector 4**2 
>   **Sector 4**2a 
>   **Sector 4**7

My HTML code is 
`<input class="location-input" ng-model="Constants.loc" typeahead="loc.title for loc in loc_getdat()" typeahead-min-length="1">`

And my controller code is

```
$scope.loc_getdat = function() {
if ($scope.Constants.loc.length > 1) {
    return $http.get('/api/v2/location_auto_suggest?loc=' + $scope.Constants.loc)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data.location_search
        });
    } 
}
```

Where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution.
 It was regarding the wait time of the typeahead. The server takes a bit of time to show results, so in the library file, the typeahead started at 0 milliseconds. I changed the `typeaheadWaitMs` time from `0` to `50`.

> (k.typeaheadWaitMs)||50

Now it is working fine.